# media size doesn't change when zooming on phone

Tags: html, ios, css, layout, responsive-design

I want to use `viewport` to support responsible layout, but when I zoom out, the size doesn't seem to fit for the screen.

When I remove the `viewport` tag, all I see on my phone is like a computer-browser's style, and when I zoom in, it just makes everything bigger(but I think it should apply the responsible CSS).

Why it doesn't change the layout? I tried on computer through changing the browser's size and it works well.

---add---

the `viewport` tag is : `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>`

Comment: Please add your meta tag where you are setting the viewport

Comment: Zooming is scaling what is there...it's not affected by media queries as such...AFAIK/